# AWS IOT button Configuration

Tags: aws-iot

Recently we purchased AWS IOT 2nd Generation Button.we are trying to configure the button as per AWS documentation.

But our LED pattern is showing Short-Short-Short (blue-white-red(5 sec)) .We dont know why this is happened.

It is directly connected to the Modem.But it is not connecting as wifi enabled or Mobile hotspot.

Question:
1) How to diagonize the connectivity issue.
2) Is there any limitation on wifi Speed.
3) All our Wifi is Open wifi (but we should register in the common site)

What will be the problem on this?How to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1. Press the button for more than 5 sec, you will see a blue light and then do the connections again.
 2.There is no limitation on your wifi speed as such.
3. That should not be a problem. I myself have two buttons. Both works fine.

One suggestion, if you are using AWS console or the website and doing the connection manually (i.e. downloading and uploading the certificate manually, etc.), try their mobile app. It should work and it's easy to use. If you are using AWS IOT mobile app, try the web version.

It should work in both the cases. Hope this helps.